# Using Linux Wildcard character in Perl Script

Tags: linux, perl, append

I have two files.

~/directory1/7120599_S1.txt

```
hello world!
```

~/directory2/7120599_S7.txt

```
bye world!
```

I'm looking for Perl code that will append the contents of `7120599_S1.txt` to the end of `7120599_S7.txt`. The following command works in Linux:

> $ cat ~/directory1/7120599_S1.txt >> ~/directory2/7120599_S*.txt

New ~/directory2/7120599_S7.txt

```
hello world!
bye world!
```

But for some reason this doesn't work in Perl

```
system "cat ~/directory1/7120599_S1.txt >> ~/directory2/7120599_S*.txt"
```

Instead it creates a new file in `directory2` called `7120599_S*.txt`. How do I get Perl to recognize the Linux wildcard character?

Comment: What shell are you using? `echo $SHELL` And are you *sure* `~/directory2/7120599_S7.txt` already exists?

Comment: @Schwern when I typed `echo $SHELL`, I got `/bin/bash`. I think I'm using the BASH shell. `~/directory2/7120599_S7.txt` exists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we look at the [POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07):

> For the other redirection operators, the word that follows the redirection operator shall be subjected to tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal. Pathname expansion shall not be performed on the word by a non-interactive shell; an interactive shell may perform it, but shall do so only when the expansion would result in one word.

Pathname expansion refers to globs like `*.txt`.

The Bash shell does not follow POSIX precisely and tries to be more convenient and sensible, including applying pathname expansion to redirection targets even in non-interactive mode. Usually, your interactive shell will be Bash.

However, when you run `system` commands this usually runs a simpler shell that is POSIX-compliant (though that depends entirely on your operating system). Often this shell is installed as `/bin/sh`.

If you want Bash, you must run Bash explicitly, e.g.

```
system "bash", "-c", "cat ~/directory1/7120599_S1.txt >> ~/directory2/7120599_S*.txt"
```

By the way, you can force Bash to follow POSIX if you set the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable.